# Write variable value in JavaScript using ADODB Stream

Tags: javascript

I want to write the value of a variable to a file using the ADODB Stream object in JavaScript.

The variable is the return value of a function. The return value of function is binary data.

I want to write it to a file.

However, I receive an error message:

"Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another"

Below is the code:

```
function decoded()
{
var a = another_function(); // returns binary data
return a;
}

var stream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
stream.Type = 1;
stream.Open();
stream.Write(decoded()); // this line throws an error
stream.SaveToFile('decoded');
stream.Close();
```

I can write a string value successfully however not the value of a variable.

Comment: The docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675017(v=vs.85).aspx) say the argument needs to be a "Buffer
A Variant that contains an array of bytes to be written.". Is it?

Comment: You say "`// this line throws an error`", but which part of the line? Is it the call to `decoded` or the call to `Write`? What arguments does `another_function` expect?